# Storing none values within DynamoDB using boto3 avoiding column name changes

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I created a DynamoDB table and I'm attempting to store a `None` within the table.

```
import boto3

dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb', region_name='eu-west-1')
table = dynamodb.Table('test_table')

table.put_item(
                Item={
                    'ID': '1',
                    'random_value': 'value1',
                    'could_be_none': None}
)

table.put_item(
                Item={
                    'ID': '2',
                    'random_value': 'value2',
                    'could_be_none': 'Not None'}
)
```

However when the code successfully runs the resulting table shows the NULL value to be `true` and also the column name appends `(NULL)`

[image: DynamoDB column NULL with true value replacing none value]

I'm not sure why this is happening or how I can handle `None` values within DynamoDB

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind that the Console view of a DynamoDB table is trying to show you a wholistic view of the data for data that is schema-less. So when you see the `could_be_none (NULL)` the console is telling you that the column is `could_be_none`, but there may be `null` values in the table, which will be represented by `true`. In Python None is the same as null. From [Python None Keyword](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_keyword_none.asp)

> The None keyword is used to define a null value, or no value at all.

So the data in the table is correct, you have set the value to none/null. You can, as another answer states, not set the value at all.

Answer (score 1):

DynamoDB doesn't allow for empty values in columns. But it's fine if not every row has same set of columns. So I would just not add this column to the rows where you want to put `None`.

If you want keep consistency between objects in your code, which you read from DynamoDB, then check if `column_name` is in DynamoDB response, and add `column_name = None` in your object.